# How to get a hWnd of an external ProgressBar in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a Form with a progressbar, and I'm trying to upgrade the value of my pb with the value of a third-party software progressbar. How could I do?
Alternatively, how can I get a "get-list" of all the components of the other software so that i'll be able to interact with them?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please share what you tried with some code. Your question is hard to answer correctly right now.

Comment: Is your third party pb running in the same program on a different form or a completely different program?